# How to handle access token in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am new to loopback and I would like some guidance on how to enable authorization for all API path and what is the use of access token.

I have logged in with registered username,password using POST/Users/login api and got access token in reponse,related screen shot
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0EFQ.png.
 And i set that token as below
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ADI.png

And i tried GET/Users api but iam getting authorization required error

{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\loopback\lib\application.js:399:21\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\loopback\lib\model.js:322:7\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\loopback\common\models\acl.js:472:23\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3694:9\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:356:16\n    at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:936:13)\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:840:16\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3691:13\n    at apply (C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:21:25)\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:56:12\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\loopback\common\models\acl.js:454:17\n    at C:\Users\prem\Desktop\test\testauth\node_modules\loopback\common\models\role.js:273:21\n    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)"
  }
}

but its working for POST/Users/logout api with 204 as status code.

Please share any guidance how to add access token in authorization header

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ? Could you add the returned data from the request ?

Comment: {"error":{"name":"Error","status":500,"message":"could not find accessToken","stack":"Error: could not find accessToken\n at E:\\TestApp3\\node_modules\\loopback\\common\\models\\user.js:302:12\n at E:\\TestApp3\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:2016:62\n at E:\\TestApp3\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-juggler\\lib\\dao.js:1944:11\n at E:\\TestApp3\\node_modules\\loopback-datasource-

Comment: response-"could not find accessToken

Comment: Next time, please edit your post with that info. I'll answer

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo, you are using `accesstoken` as argument in the request, but the keyword is [`access_token`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Making-authenticated-requests.html)

Correct request:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/custs/logout?access_token=REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Please post again the error message (even if it looks similar or the same) on your original post